# Run TFS Agent as Service in Docker Container

Tags: docker, tfs, azure-devops, containers, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run a TFS agent as a service in a Windows Server Docker Container. I am able to get the agent running if I use the run.cmd but when attempting to configure the agent to run as a service I'm getting the error Below.

I have ensured the account is a local administrator and have tried the local system account and seem to be getting the same error. Thanks

Exit code -1073741502 returned from process: file name 'C:\TFSAgent\bin\AgentService.exe', arguments 'init'.

Command I'm using:

```
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://tfsurl --auth Negotiate --username username --password password --pool Sandbox --agent dockeragent --runasservice --windowslogonaccount
username --windowslogonpassword password --replace
```

Answer (score 0):

> Run TFS Agent as Service in Docker Container

According to the document [Define container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#requirements), which need to make sure：

> The agent must have permission to access the Docker daemon

To run a self-hosted agent in Docker, you could refer following document:

[Run a self-hosted agent in Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops)

[Running Azure DevOps private agents as docker containers](https://mohitgoyal.co/2019/01/05/running-azure-devops-private-agents-as-docker-containers/)